# Sending Mail does not work

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send a php mail for a very basic form, I receive the email of success but the email never arrives, or the received spam, nowhere. Here is the code

```
<?php
    $nombre = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $para = 'me@example.com';
    $titulo = 'ASUNTO DEL MENSAJE';
    $header = 'From: ' . $email;
    $msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";

    if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
            window.location.href = 'www.fullmecanic.com';
        </script>";
    } else {
        echo 'Falló el envio';
    }
?>
```

As previously name, I receive the message of success but does not email.

Comment: Your need to configure your server

Comment: You need to provide us with more info. Are you using it on remote server or local development environment? Do you have local mail server installed if it's local environment eg. Papercut (https://papercut.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I'm working on a Linux ubuntu server and install sendmail

Comment: You check your junk box?

Comment: yes, but there is nothing

Comment: whats the mail-server log say?